# Using connected wallet to authenticate endpoint for dApp?

Tags: ethereum, metamask, ethers.js

I have a pure Typescript dApp that has no server behind it. The user connects their MetaMask wallet and mints an NFT from the site. I want to provide an affiliate program so partners can give out their affiliate link and anyone who purchases an NFT they will get a percentage fee.

If the affiliate identifier is in the query string parameters, I will write it to the user's cookie. Then I can call an endpoint with the user's public wallet address and transaction identifier when they complete the mint. Or if they leave and come back, the affiliate id is in the cookie to pick up from there.

My challenge is how can I authenticate that endpoint if the dApp is pure javascript with no server behind it? What can stop anyone from just calling this endpoint with a bunch of wallets and affiliate codes?

Could there be a way to use the user's connected wallet to sign a message and authenticate with the endpoint that way? It would almost be like OAuth but for crypto. I want to keep this simple though.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> My challenge is how can I authenticate that endpoint if the dApp is pure javascript with no server behind it? What can stop anyone from just calling this endpoint with a bunch of wallets and affiliate codes?

Usually you don't. You can pass the information in the mint transaction.

> My challenge is how can I authenticate that endpoint if the dApp is pure javascript with no server behind it? What can stop anyone from just calling this endpoint with a bunch of wallets and affiliate codes?

You can make users to sign in to your service using [Ethereum Sign In](https://login.xyz/). This needs a backend, though. You are not going to get more information than in the mint transaction (the user address).